# How to access button of opened form?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

```
    private void rbnbtnPageSetup_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (IsFormOpen(typeof(GUI.Printing)))
        {

        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Please Open Printing Form");
        }
    }
```

`IsFormOpen(Type t)` is a method that return true if printing Form is open.

I want to open the print preview button in Printing form. Make sure i don't want to open new printing form. My requirement is if printing form is open then press print prieview button of that form.

**Method i have used to check form is open or not:**

```
    //Checking Form is open or not
    public bool IsFormOpen(Type formType)
    {
        foreach (Form form in Application.OpenForms)
        {
            if (form.GetType() == formType)
                return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of clicking button on another form just move 'PreviewClick' logic to separate method, make it public and fire it.

So in your preview form, create new method:

```
private void PrintButtonClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     Preview();
}

public void Preview()
{
     //... preview logic here
}
```

and then you can do this:

```
private void rbnbtnPageSetup_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (IsFormOpen(typeof(GUI.Printing)))
    {
         var frm = Application.OpenForms.OfType<Form>().FirstOrDefault(x => x.GetType() == typeof(GUI.Printing)); //this retrieves the preview form
         frm.Show();
         frm.Preview();
    }
    else
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Please Open Printing Form");
    }
}
```

I do not see any problems with my LINQ way but just to be sure use the same approach to get form as to check if it is opened. So change this line

```
var frm = Application.OpenForms.OfType<Form>().FirstOrDefault(x => x.GetType() == typeof(GUI.Printing)); //this retrieves the preview form
```

to this: **LAST EDIT**

```
GUI.Printing preview = null;
foreach (Form form in Application.OpenForms)
{
    if (form.GetType() == typeof(GUI.Printing))
    {
        preview = (GUI.Printing)form;
        break;
    }
}

if (preview == null)
{
    return;
}

preview.Show();
preview.Preview();
```

This has to work or otherwise something very strange is going on in your code.

Comment: var frm returns null value. Why?:(

Comment: Is `Gui.Printing` form? or some other type?

Comment: Very strange, always worked for me. Can you show me `IsFormOpen` method code?

Comment: I have added that method below my question. Please check.

Comment: Nop. It gives same result. If i create new object and calling preview method will be working fine but that wasn't my requirement. I have created new solution & try this. Even same result dude.:(

Comment: This was my error message:
'System.Windows.Forms.Form' does not contain a definition for 'Preview' and no extension method 'Preview' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Windows.Forms.Form' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Answer (score 1):

Keep a reference to your printing form, and give it a public method `Print()` and a public method `ShowPrintPreview()`. Then whenever you want to print or preview something, you just call the appropriate method.